# Init and use C++ std::string as array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, stdstring, setvalue

I want to use a std::string for dynamic string handling. The data is append and append to a string, sometime I wan't to set the value for the character at index i. I don't know how many character will be added to string. Something like dynamic collection in .NET.
When I allocate a std::string in C++

```
std::string s;
```

and try to set element at index i for it:

```
s[0] = 'a';
```

It will through an error related to memory.
A stupid way is init it with exist data and replace them later:

```
std::string s = generate1000chars();
s[2] = 'c';
```

Is there a way to init a string that allow manipulate character at index i, like a char array?

Comment: You should [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) the string before using.

Comment: Also take a look at `push_back` and `operator+=` if you want to append some characters.

Comment: I meant `std::string s(1000, 'a');`, the second constructor from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). Of course, it should be slower than just resizing.

Comment: Thank yous. Now I am using a while loop, have a global totalSize value, just increase it and resize :) This is best for value assign at index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try a wrapper function like

```
std::string& SetChar(std::string& str, char ch, size_t index)
{
    if (str.length() <= index)
    {
        str.resize(index + 1);
    }
    str[index] = ch;
    return str;
}
```

So that the string can auto extend if needed.
(Modified to a better signature)

Comment: We even have a Well Cooked solution here. Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::string::resize()` to resize it and fill it in later:

```
std::string s;
s.resize(1000);

//later..
s[2] = 'c';
```